# For bitbucket, what is the difference between having a team work on a repo and having a personal repo that everyone on the team works on?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am porting a project that was originally only worked on by me to bitbucket so that someone else may help me.  We do not want this to be an open source project and it should only be the two of us working on it.  The question is whether I make it a personal repo and then invite him to it or whether I make a team that the two of us are on and then have a repo for the team.

Is there a difference between the two approaches?  Any benefits to either one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't have any difference between the two approaches relative to work on a project, it's only one feature to help you to organize your projects and teams, but have no differences.

Comment: If I were to invite my team mate to the personal repo would he need my password to clone it or since he was invited would he be able to use his own.  If he does need my password does making a team change this at all?

Comment: @MatthewLudwig the persons who you invite need to have an account on bitbucket, and you will share your project inside of Settings > Access management, adding "bitbucket" users. Then you don't need to share your password, each developer will clone the project with its own user.