# Bitbucket branch management and team login

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, access-control

We're trying to force ourselves not to push directly to master, so we used "Branch management" in order to "Limit pushes to specific users and groups" We did [Bitbucket branch management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580913/bitbucket-branch-management) and it works for our users.

But one of our teammates unintentionally kept pushing to master, because they were using team login rather than their user login.

How can we prevent this from happening?

I've read [For bitbucket, what is the difference between having a team work on a repo and having a personal repo that everyone on the team works on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233442/for-bitbucket-what-is-the-difference-between-having-a-team-work-on-a-repo-and-h) but with "Settings > Access management" we can't restrict the team (the team is the owner of the repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team account should not be used directly to authenticate as. You will find that you cannot use the team credentials to log into Bitbucket (and haven't been able to do so for a [considerable amount of time](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/01/14/important-changes-are-coming-to-teams/)).

The inability to configure branch restrictions for the team account reflects this notion that it is not to be used directly.

However, we then dropped the ball when we failed to lock down other paths like pushing/pulling.

We are aware of this issue and we are (finally) in the process of locking down git/hg access for team accounts in the near future and so even you do nothing, this problem will eventually solve itself.

For now however, I can offer to reset your team's password so that it can no longer be used accidentally. Please email us at support@bitbucket.org, referring to this page and mentioning my name to make this happen.